# Remove the duplicates in Recipients field in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

currently I have a macro that filters the data based on Names in **G Column** and picks the email Id's from the **H Column** and puts them into the Email template "To" field. The problem here is we would be having duplicate mail ID's and those need to removed from the "To" field.

Currently, I'm using the below code:

```
EmailTo = Join(Application.Transpose(UpdatedPymtsFile.Sheets(1).Range("H2:H" & UpdatedPymtFileRows1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value), ";")
```

This is going to join the email IDs, and How to remove the duplicates from it? please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have Excel365 you can incorporate  `Worksheetfunction.Unique` to eliminate duplicates

Comment: @chrisneilsen, I have used the unique function as you said, but instead of removing duplicates, it is picking only one email ID. Here's the code I have used:

`EmailTo = Join(Application.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Unique(UpdatedPymtsFile.Sheets("Data").Range("H2:H" & UpdatedPymtFileRows1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value)), ";") `

If I remove the Unique function, it is throwing Run time error 13 - type mismatch

Please help!!

Comment: You've got a lot going on in a single line of code.  I'd suggest breaking it out into multiple lines, returning each step to a variable.   Single step through the code and examine each result to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Do a manual test on a copy of that ID column and see what happens with unique(), once you see what results you get and **why** then you can craft the vba code as appropriate.

Comment: I have checked it manually, I have been getting wrong in this statement.

`UpdatedPymtsFile.Sheets("Data").Range("H2:H" & UpdatedPymtFileRows1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value`

This is picking only the first visible cell. When I use specialcells syntax, it is not working. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

`UpdatedPymtsFile.Sheets("Data").Range("H2:H" & UpdatedPymtFileRows1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a Range object.  Since you are calling out Visible cells only on a filtered list, that range will likely be a set of non contiguous areas.

Your problem is that for a range with more than one area, the .Value property returns value(s) of only the first area.

A solution is to capture the range into a Range variable,  then loop the .Areas collection

```
Dim rng As Range, ar As Range

Set rng = UpdatedPymtsFile.Sheets("Data").Range("H2:H" & UpdatedPymtFileRows1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
EmailTo = ""
For Each ar In rng.Areas
    EmailTo = ";" & EmailTo Join(Application.Transpose(ar.Value), ";")

Next
EmailTo = Mid$(EmailTo, 2)
```

You will need to add error handling in case the filter has no visible cells.